# PhantomJS with embedded web server uses only one CPU

Tags: javascript, highcharts, mongoose, phantomjs

I have a problem using PhantomJS with web server module in a multi-threaded way, with concurrent requests.
I am using PhantomJS 2.0 to create highstock graphs on the server-side with Java, as explained [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) (and the code [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/java)).
It works well, and when testing graphs of several sizes, I got results that are pretty consistent, about 0.4 seconds to create a graph.

The code that I linked to was originally published by the highcharts team, and it is also used in their export server at http://export.highcharts.com/. In order to support concurrent requests, it keeps a pool of spawned PhantomJS processes, and basically its model is one phantomjs instance per concurrent request.

I saw that the webserver module supports up to 10 concurrent requests (explained here), so I thought I can tap on that to keep a lesser number of PhantomJS processes in my pool. However, when I tried to utilize more threads, I experienced a linear slow down, as if PhantomJS was using only one CPU. This slow-down is shown as follows (for a single PhantomJS instance):

1 client thread, average request time 0.44 seconds.
2 client threads, average request time 0.76 seconds.
4 client threads, average request time 1.5 seconds.

Is this a known limitation of PhantomJS? Is there a way around it?

(question also posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/48PLdYftCJQ))

Comment: You forgot some *here* links.

Comment: The more interesting question might be, why did the time not double by going from 1 to 2 clients and why did it double by going from 2 to 4 clients.

Comment: It nearly doubled, I think you can account it to the margin of error in the measurements.

Comment: I'm doing almost the exact same thing as you, "HighCharts to images via phantomjs"  Have you found a solution to getting increased performance?  I'm looking into CefSharp which gives a bit more control than PhantomJS.  I tried doing page pooling but as per your question, this has minimal effect.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148288/phantomjs-keep-page-open

Comment: Would something like this be a workaround?
https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Is this a known limitation of PhantomJS?**

Yes, it is an expected limitation, because PhantomJS uses the same WebKit engine for everything and since JavaScript is single-threaded, this effectively means that every request will be handled one after the other (possibly interlocked), but never *at the same time*. The average overall time will increase linearly with each client.

The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) says:

> There is currently a limit of 10 concurrent requests; any other requests will be queued up.

There is a difference between the notions of concurrent and parallel requests. *Concurrent* simply means that the tasks finish non-deterministically. It doesn't mean that the instructions that the tasks are made of are executed in parallel on different (virtual) cores.

> **Is there a way around it?**

Other than running your server tasks through child_process, **no**. The way JavaScript supports multi-threading is by using Web Workers, but a worker is sandboxed and has no access to `require` and therefore cannot create pages to do stuff.

Comment: Web workers enable multi-threaded execution, but I don't know if out can use them for concurrent requests. This is an interesting idea.

Comment: I just tried it with a WebWorker, but sadly there is no `require` in the worker, so there is no way to make the processing parallel.

Comment: If I run multiple tabs in chrome, are they not running in multiple threads separate from each other?

Comment: @Yoni If you have multiple tabs in Chrome you even have multiple processes and not just threads. You can certainly do this with PhantomJS, because it has a child_process module.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It doesn't matter to me if it's threads or processes. I can already launch multiple phantomjs processes, like highcharts do on their export server, but I am trying to reduce the number of processes. I am not going to implement something with child_process on my own either. My question is about expectation - phantomjs has an embedded web server that claims to support concurrent requests, which logically and feature-wise (for me) acts like multiple tabs. I expect it to be multi-threaded and utilize more than one CPU, and it appears that it doesn't.

Comment: @Yoni Yes, the requests are concurrent, but not parallel, because no additional threads or processes are utilized.

Comment: @ArtjomB. exactly :) this is also in the title of the question. Do I have any way to make it utilize additional threads?

Comment: @Yoni I that's exactly what I said in my answer: No.